# Submit search not working due to space in the search input

Tags: php, regex

When I search something having only a word, it shows the result but when i search something having two words, it does not show the result. May be its due to the space between them...Any solutions for this???

```
This is the code which I am using:

<?php include("config.php");
include("session-user.php");
if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] != "") {
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_title LIKE '%$searchq%' and is_delete = '0'";
$sql=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $product_title = $row['product_title'];
    $id = $row['product_id'];}?>
<script>
    window.location="product.php?pid=<?php echo $id?>";
</script>
<?php
}
?>

<div class="ui-widget">
<input id="automplete-3" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
</div>
```

Comment: use trim() like `$searchq = trim($_POST['search']);` it will remove trailing space not between 2 characters or words.

Comment: `$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);` this covert your space to blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
```

covert your space to blank

**For example**

```
$searchq="one two";//output onetwo
```

Add space in your regex as

```
echo $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z\s]#i","",$searchq);
                                       ^^^^
```

It will produce

**For example**

```
$searchq="one two";//output one two
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z ]#i","",$searchq);
```

give the space between ("#[^0-9a-z ]#i"